# Ubuntu keeps disabling ipv6 after kernel updates

Tags: networking, drivers, grub2, kernel, ipv6

Every time I have kernel updates and I install them, I find the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1"` added to my `/etc/default/grub`. I need to manually delete it every time, `update-grub` and reboot.

How can I find why it is added? And - more importantly - how can I make it stop doing so?

**EDIT 2021-02-27:**

I've updated system today and it happened again. I checked `/etc/default/grub` before and after upgrade and I'm 100% it happened during this very upgrade - it is the only thing that happened and something added this line. Below is the console output from entire upgrade execution:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libpciaccess0 linux-headers-5.4.0-62 linux-headers-5.4.0-62-generic linux-image-5.4.0-62-generic linux-modules-5.4.0-62-generic linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-62-generic python3-xkit ubuntu-drivers-common
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-5.4.0-66 linux-headers-5.4.0-66-generic linux-image-5.4.0-66-generic linux-modules-5.4.0-66-generic linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-66-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  dnsmasq-base gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 grub-common grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libldap-2.4-2 libldap-common libpython3.8 libpython3.8-minimal libpython3.8-stdlib libtiff5 linux-generic
  linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic linux-image-virtual linux-libc-dev pollinate python3.8 python3.8-minimal qemu-guest-agent screen
24 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 86.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 361 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libpython3.8 amd64 3.8.5-1~20.04.2 [1,624 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 python3.8 amd64 3.8.5-1~20.04.2 [373 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libpython3.8-stdlib amd64 3.8.5-1~20.04.2 [1,671 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 python3.8-minimal amd64 3.8.5-1~20.04.2 [1,899 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libpython3.8-minimal amd64 3.8.5-1~20.04.2 [715 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 qemu-guest-agent amd64 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.14 [193 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 dnsmasq-base amd64 2.80-1.1ubuntu1.3 [314 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libtiff5 amd64 4.1.0+git191117-2ubuntu0.20.04.1 [162 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 amd64 2.40.0+dfsg-3ubuntu0.2 [168 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common all 2.40.0+dfsg-3ubuntu0.2 [4,652 B]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 amd64 2.40.0+dfsg-3ubuntu0.2 [8,268 B]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 grub-pc amd64 2.04-1ubuntu26.9 [125 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 grub2-common amd64 2.04-1ubuntu26.9 [592 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 grub-pc-bin amd64 2.04-1ubuntu26.9 [971 kB]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 grub-common amd64 2.04-1ubuntu26.9 [1,877 kB]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libldap-common all 2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.7 [17.1 kB]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libldap-2.4-2 amd64 2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.7 [155 kB]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-modules-5.4.0-66-generic amd64 5.4.0-66.74 [14.5 MB]
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-image-5.4.0-66-generic amd64 5.4.0-66.74 [8,891 kB]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-66-generic amd64 5.4.0-66.74 [38.6 MB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-generic amd64 5.4.0.66.69 [1,896 B]
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-image-generic amd64 5.4.0.66.69 [2,636 B]
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-5.4.0-66 all 5.4.0-66.74 [11.0 MB]
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-5.4.0-66-generic amd64 5.4.0-66.74 [1,256 kB]
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-generic amd64 5.4.0.66.69 [2,496 B]
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-image-virtual amd64 5.4.0.66.69 [2,604 B]
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 5.4.0-66.74 [1,139 kB]
Get:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 pollinate all 4.33-3ubuntu1.20.04.1 [22.6 kB]
Get:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 screen amd64 4.8.0-1ubuntu0.1 [577 kB]
Fetched 86.8 MB in 2s (41.6 MB/s)
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 189380 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-libpython3.8_3.8.5-1~20.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.8:amd64 (3.8.5-1~20.04.2) over (3.8.5-1~20.04) ...
Preparing to unpack .../01-python3.8_3.8.5-1~20.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3.8 (3.8.5-1~20.04.2) over (3.8.5-1~20.04) ...
Preparing to unpack .../02-libpython3.8-stdlib_3.8.5-1~20.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.8-stdlib:amd64 (3.8.5-1~20.04.2) over (3.8.5-1~20.04) ...
Preparing to unpack .../03-python3.8-minimal_3.8.5-1~20.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3.8-minimal (3.8.5-1~20.04.2) over (3.8.5-1~20.04) ...
Preparing to unpack .../04-libpython3.8-minimal_3.8.5-1~20.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.8-minimal:amd64 (3.8.5-1~20.04.2) over (3.8.5-1~20.04) ...
Preparing to unpack .../05-qemu-guest-agent_1%3a4.2-3ubuntu6.14_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking qemu-guest-agent (1:4.2-3ubuntu6.14) over (1:4.2-3ubuntu6.12) ...
Preparing to unpack .../06-dnsmasq-base_2.80-1.1ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking dnsmasq-base (2.80-1.1ubuntu1.3) over (2.80-1.1ubuntu1.2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../07-libtiff5_4.1.0+git191117-2ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libtiff5:amd64 (4.1.0+git191117-2ubuntu0.20.04.1) over (4.1.0+git191117-2build1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../08-libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0_2.40.0+dfsg-3ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:amd64 (2.40.0+dfsg-3ubuntu0.2) over (2.40.0+dfsg-3ubuntu0.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../09-libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common_2.40.0+dfsg-3ubuntu0.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common (2.40.0+dfsg-3ubuntu0.2) over (2.40.0+dfsg-3ubuntu0.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../10-gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0_2.40.0+dfsg-3ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0:amd64 (2.40.0+dfsg-3ubuntu0.2) over (2.40.0+dfsg-3ubuntu0.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../11-grub-pc_2.04-1ubuntu26.9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking grub-pc (2.04-1ubuntu26.9) over (2.04-1ubuntu26.8) ...
Preparing to unpack .../12-grub2-common_2.04-1ubuntu26.9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking grub2-common (2.04-1ubuntu26.9) over (2.04-1ubuntu26.8) ...
Preparing to unpack .../13-grub-pc-bin_2.04-1ubuntu26.9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking grub-pc-bin (2.04-1ubuntu26.9) over (2.04-1ubuntu26.8) ...
Preparing to unpack .../14-grub-common_2.04-1ubuntu26.9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking grub-common (2.04-1ubuntu26.9) over (2.04-1ubuntu26.8) ...
Preparing to unpack .../15-libldap-common_2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.7_all.deb ...
Unpacking libldap-common (2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.7) over (2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.6) ...
Preparing to unpack .../16-libldap-2.4-2_2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libldap-2.4-2:amd64 (2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.7) over (2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-5.4.0-66-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../17-linux-modules-5.4.0-66-generic_5.4.0-66.74_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-5.4.0-66-generic (5.4.0-66.74) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-5.4.0-66-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../18-linux-image-5.4.0-66-generic_5.4.0-66.74_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-5.4.0-66-generic (5.4.0-66.74) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-66-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../19-linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-66-generic_5.4.0-66.74_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-66-generic (5.4.0-66.74) ...
Preparing to unpack .../20-linux-generic_5.4.0.66.69_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-generic (5.4.0.66.69) over (5.4.0.65.68) ...
Preparing to unpack .../21-linux-image-generic_5.4.0.66.69_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-generic (5.4.0.66.69) over (5.4.0.65.68) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-5.4.0-66.
Preparing to unpack .../22-linux-headers-5.4.0-66_5.4.0-66.74_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-5.4.0-66 (5.4.0-66.74) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-5.4.0-66-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../23-linux-headers-5.4.0-66-generic_5.4.0-66.74_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-5.4.0-66-generic (5.4.0-66.74) ...
Preparing to unpack .../24-linux-headers-generic_5.4.0.66.69_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-generic (5.4.0.66.69) over (5.4.0.65.68) ...
Preparing to unpack .../25-linux-image-virtual_5.4.0.66.69_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-virtual (5.4.0.66.69) over (5.4.0.65.68) ...
Preparing to unpack .../26-linux-libc-dev_5.4.0-66.74_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-libc-dev:amd64 (5.4.0-66.74) over (5.4.0-65.73) ...
Preparing to unpack .../27-pollinate_4.33-3ubuntu1.20.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking pollinate (4.33-3ubuntu1.20.04.1) over (4.33-3ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../28-screen_4.8.0-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking screen (4.8.0-1ubuntu0.1) over (4.8.0-1) ...
Setting up libpython3.8-minimal:amd64 (3.8.5-1~20.04.2) ...
Setting up libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common (2.40.0+dfsg-3ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up qemu-guest-agent (1:4.2-3ubuntu6.14) ...
Setting up linux-libc-dev:amd64 (5.4.0-66.74) ...
Setting up screen (4.8.0-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up linux-headers-5.4.0-66 (5.4.0-66.74) ...
Setting up dnsmasq-base (2.80-1.1ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libldap-common (2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.7) ...
Setting up linux-modules-5.4.0-66-generic (5.4.0-66.74) ...
Setting up grub-common (2.04-1ubuntu26.9) ...
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
Setting up pollinate (4.33-3ubuntu1.20.04.1) ...
Setting up python3.8-minimal (3.8.5-1~20.04.2) ...
Setting up libtiff5:amd64 (4.1.0+git191117-2ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up libpython3.8-stdlib:amd64 (3.8.5-1~20.04.2) ...
Setting up python3.8 (3.8.5-1~20.04.2) ...
Setting up linux-image-5.4.0-66-generic (5.4.0-66.74) ...
I: /vmlinuz.old is now a symlink to boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-65-generic
I: /initrd.img.old is now a symlink to boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-65-generic
I: /vmlinuz is now a symlink to boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-66-generic
I: /initrd.img is now a symlink to boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-66-generic
Setting up grub2-common (2.04-1ubuntu26.9) ...
Setting up linux-headers-5.4.0-66-generic (5.4.0-66.74) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.4.0-66-generic

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
make -j2 KERNELRELEASE=5.4.0-66-generic -C /lib/modules/5.4.0-66-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/wireguard/1.0.20201112/build.......
cleaning build area...

DKMS: build completed.

wireguard.ko:
Running module version sanity check.

Good news! Module version 1.0.20201112 for wireguard.ko
exactly matches what is already found in kernel 5.4.0-66-generic.
DKMS will not replace this module.
You may override by specifying --force.

depmod...

DKMS: install completed.
   ...done.
Setting up libldap-2.4-2:amd64 (2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.7) ...
Setting up linux-headers-generic (5.4.0.66.69) ...
Setting up linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-66-generic (5.4.0-66.74) ...
Setting up grub-pc-bin (2.04-1ubuntu26.9) ...
Setting up grub-pc (2.04-1ubuntu26.9) ...
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-66-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-65-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-65-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-64-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-64-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-62-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-62-generic
done
Setting up libpython3.8:amd64 (3.8.5-1~20.04.2) ...
Setting up libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:amd64 (2.40.0+dfsg-3ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up linux-image-virtual (5.4.0.66.69) ...
Setting up linux-image-generic (5.4.0.66.69) ...
Setting up linux-generic (5.4.0.66.69) ...
Setting up gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0:amd64 (2.40.0+dfsg-3ubuntu0.2) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.4) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.16-2ubuntu2.1) ...
Processing triggers for install-info (6.7.0.dfsg.2-5) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.4.0-66-generic (5.4.0-66.74) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.4.0-66-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-66-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/x-grub-legacy-ec2:
Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
Searching for default file ... found: /boot/grub/default
Testing for an existing GRUB menu.lst file ... found: /boot/grub/menu.lst
Searching for splash image ... none found, skipping ...
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-65-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-64-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-62-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-66-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-65-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-64-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-62-generic
Replacing config file /run/grub/menu.lst with new version
Updating /boot/grub/menu.lst ... done

/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-66-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-66-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-65-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-65-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-64-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-64-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-62-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-62-generic
done
```

Among packages what brings my attention are `wireguard` and `grub-pc`. I'm not sure how safe it is to reinstall them (for testing purpose) - is there a risk I will lose their current configuration?
What else should I check?

**EDIT 2021-04-29:**

There was another attempt to alter the `/etc/default/grub` and this time I did have the immutable flag set on it, so I saw this error during upgrades:

```
Setting up grub-pc (2.04-1ubuntu26.11) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/grub-pc.postinst: line 28: /etc/default/grub: Operation not permitted
dpkg: error processing package grub-pc (--configure):
 installed grub-pc package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

I've reviewed file `/var/lib/dpkg/info/grub-pc.postinst` but it's quite big and complicated script. Nevertheless I saw it often refers to different files from `/var/lib/....` so I did: `grep -R ipv6.disable /var/lib/` and here's an interesting line I found:

```
/var/lib/ucf/cache/:etc:default:grub:GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1"
```

This is the only occurrence found. I viewed this whole file and it's basically some old (?) version of grub file, which has this ipv6 disabled.

1. Why is it there? What's its purpose?
2. Is it needed? Can I delete it?
3. Is it safe to keep the `/etc/default/grub` immutable forever? (this is a VPS running in a cloud, thus I worry if cloud provider requires some updates to this file occasionally to align it with the infrastructure). On one hand I would prefer to go back to normal (to remove immutable flag), but on the other hand I'm worried of facing the issue again in some time and I forgot to verify post-upgrade.

Comment: I don't know of any Ubuntu package that automatically edits ```/etc/default/grub```; that seems quite obnoxious as the correct way to do something like that would be to drop a file in ```/etc/default/grub.d```. You could set the file immutable and reinstall your current kernel and see what complains? ```sudo chattr +i /etc/default/grub; sudo apt reinstall linux-image…```. As it seems to happen when you install a kernel you could also look at the kernel package hooks: ```grep -r ipv6.disable /etc/kernel```. Please update us - I'm intrigued!

Comment: It seems it's not kernel upgrade after all. That was my closest guess according to what I remember doing just before it appeared again. I've reinstalled (without immutable flag) the kernel and it did not re-appear. Also grepping `/etc/kernel` did not find anything (I also explored it manually to find anything suspicious). So far no leads. I will keep this question here and keep observing the system. Maybe next time I will find new lead and get back here with it.

Comment: @grifferz Just calling you out, as it happened again and now I have more evidence - added to the original post.

Comment: Any reason why you did not make it immutable like I suggested? Whichever package tries to alter it will encounter an error thereby revealing itself. If you ever need to alter it you can just ```chattr -i``` before doing so. I can't imagine what's doing it but this is still my best idea for finding out. Another thing you could try is grepping through all the postinst scripts in ```/var/lib/dpkg/info``` for the exact string that is being added.

Comment: I just didn't know if it's a good idea to keep it immutable forever. I was afraid of a grub upgrade that would need to change it for a good reason. I will set the flag now and keep observing. Thanks!

Comment: @grifferz sorry to bother you again, but I got the guilty one. Would you mind looking and my last update (labeled with 2021-04-29) and perhaps answer my questions in the end?